# What is the DFT of $x(2n)$ if you know the DFT of $x(n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $X(\omega)$ is the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of a sequence of arbitrary complex numbers $x(n)$. What is the DFT of a new sequence $x(2n)$?

Here is my thinking:

The DFT of $x(2n) = $ $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(2n)e^{-j \omega n}  $$

But at this point I am stuck.  Somehow the answer is $X(\frac{\omega}{2})$

Comment: In general, your conjectured answer is not correct:
\begin{align}
X\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(n)e^{-\frac{j\omega n}{2}}\\
&= \sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty x(2r)e^{-\frac{j\omega(2r)}{2}}+ \sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty x(2r+1)e^{-\frac{j\omega (2r+1)}{2}}\\
&= \sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty x(2r)e^{-j\omega r}+ e^{-\frac{j\omega}{2}}\sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty x(2r+1) e^{-j\omega r}\ ,
\end{align}
but the second term of the final sum on the right of this equation is not necessarily zero.

Comment: So I can see a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJXapJud2sI  that solves this question for continuous signals, and i'm wondering if there is a way to do the same for discrete signals.  Obviously we cannot take derivatives like they do in the video.  So does this mean we need to use difference equations?

Comment: I think this guy answers my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7uOCE3wKaU   Do you agree?

Comment: No, I don't agree.  In the sums $\ \sum_\limits{n=-\infty}^\infty x(np)e^{-j\Omega n}\ $ and $\ \sum_\limits{\frac{m}{p}=-\infty}^ {\frac{m}{p}=-\infty} x(m)e^{-j\left(\frac{\Omega}{p}\right)m}\ $, the argument of $\ x\ $ (i.e $\ np\ $ in the first sum, $\ m\ $ in the second) runs from $\ -\infty\ $ to $\ \infty $ *only over multiples of* $\ p\ $.  In the sum $\ \sum_\limits{m=-\infty}^\infty x(m)e^{-j\left(\frac{\Omega}{p}\right)m}\ $, however, this has been replaced illegitimately by a sum over all the integers.